# jquery search works for all columns instead of some html table

Tags: jquery, html

Just want to add search possibility to loaded table using jquery, but the code below works for the all columns only.

I would like to make it work for some of the cells, in this case, the 3 first.
Could you please check the code and help me to find my mistake:

Here is my HTML code:

`<input type="text" id="buscar" name="buscar"/>`

here is my js code:

```
$("#buscar").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#borrar').css('display', 'inline');
    if (value.length > 1) {
        $("#proveedores tbody>tr").hide();
        $("#proveedores td:contains-ci('" + value + "')").parent("tr").show();
    } else {
        $("#proveedores tbody>tr").show();
        if (value === "")
            $('#borrar').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    "contains-ci": function (elem, i, match, array) {
        var iner = elem.innerHTML;
        var cad = match[3];
        iner = $.trim(iner);
        cad = $.trim(cad);
        if (iner.substring(2, 3) === '-') {
            cad = cad.substring(0, 2) + "-" + cad.substring(2);
        }
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || $(elem).text() || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((cad || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
});
```

and an example of the table:

```
<table class="tabla" id="proveedores">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Numero
            </th>
            <th>
                Razon social
            </th>
            <th>
                CUIT
            </th>
            <th>
                Modalidad de pago
            </th>
            <th>
                Vencido meses anteriores
            </th>
            <th>
                A vencer este mes
            </th>
            <th>
                Subtotal
            </th>
            <th>
                Semana 88/89
            </th>
            <th>
                No vencido
            </th>
            <th>
                Anticipos
            </th>
            <th>
                TOTAL ADEUDADO
            </th>
            <th>
                Cheques en cartera
            </th>
            <th>
                Cheques entregados no cobrados
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>">
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                fooexample
            </td>
            <td>
                30-707070-2
            </td>
            <td>
                contado
            </td>
            <td>
                22222222
            </td>
            <td>
                22222222
            </td>
            <td>
                22222222
            </td>
            <td>
                22222222
            </td>
            <td>
                22222222
            </td>
            <td>
                22222222
            </td>
            <td>
                22222222
            </td>
            <td>
                22222222
            </td>
            <td>
                22222222
            </td>
        </tr>
    22222222
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter selectors in order to get the 3rd column, use `:nth-child(3)`.

Remove this, which is not working, since it substrings the value entered in the seach field... Not the elements inner HTML.

```
if (iner.substring(2, 3) === '-') {
    cad = cad.substring(0, 2) + "-" + cad.substring(2);
}
```

Here is your script, which is working fine in [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/jBqoMM).

```
$("#buscar").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#borrar').css('display', 'inline');
    if (value.length > 1) {
        $("#proveedores tbody>tr").hide();
        $("#proveedores tr td:nth-child(3):contains-ci('" + value + "')").parent("tr").show();
    } else {
        $("#proveedores tbody>tr").show();
        if (value === "")
            $('#borrar').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    "contains-ci": function (elem, i, match, array) {
        var iner = elem.innerHTML;
        var cad = match[3];
        console.log(cad);
        iner = $.trim(iner);
        cad = $.trim(cad);
        /*if (iner.substring(2, 3) === '-') {
            cad = cad.substring(0, 2) + "-" + cad.substring(2);
        }*/
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || $(elem).text() || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((cad || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT**

In fact, you also could use the "standard" `:contains()` and completely remove the extend function.

See in [this second CodePen](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/NpNZwY?editors=1011).

```
$("#buscar").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#borrar').css('display', 'inline');
    if (value.length > 1) {
        $("#proveedores tbody>tr").hide();
        $("#proveedores tr td:nth-child(3):contains('" + value + "')").parent("tr").show();
    } else {
        $("#proveedores tbody>tr").show();
        if (value === "")
            $('#borrar').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! work perfectly. 
Yeah you right, with contains, i don't need the extend fucntion, but i need it for the case sensitive and the addition of de character "-" in case of search in third column (the columns i need to searh for are 1, 2 and 3).